# Throttling between API Gateway and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

From my understanding, API Gateway by default has a 1000 RPS limit--when this is crossed, it will begin throttling calls and returning 429 error codes. Past the Gateway, Lambda has a 100 concurrent invocation limit, and when this is crossed, it will begin throttling calls and returning 500 (or 502) error codes.

Given that, when viewing my graph on Cloudwatch, I would expect my number of throttled calls to be closer to the number of 4XX errors, or at least above the number of 5XX errors, because the calls must pass through API Gateway first in order to get to Lambda at all. However, it looks like the number of throttled calls is closer to the number of 5XX errors.

Is there something I might be missing from the way I'm reading the graph?

Comment: *"I would expect my number of throttled calls to be closer to the number of 4XX errors"*  Why?  Those are two unrelated things, are they not?  You have said, yourself, that a Lambda throttle generates a 5XX error, while an API Gateway rate limiting event generates a 4XX error, which is by definition not going to tally as a Lambda throttle, because Lambda never sees the request since API Gateway rejected it out-of-hand.

Comment: Confirming... your "throttled" metric in Cloudwatch is a Lambda metric, not API Gateway... isn't it?

Comment: That makes sense..if that's the case, is there any way to see the calls throttled by API Gateway?

Comment: I don't think so, since they are probably rejected very early in the processing path... but that's just an intuitive guess.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, I'll remember to look into that separately. Last question about this, hopefully--do my other notes about the 4XX codes from API Gateway and 5XX codes from Lambda seem correct to you?

Comment: Yes, although both the API-GW 1000 req/s and Lambda 100 concurrent invocation limits are soft limits that AWS support will increase for you, [if you ask](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html).  You don't need a paid support plan in order to submit this type of support request -- all you need is a brief explanation of your use case to justify the increase.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how long it takes for your Lambda function to execute and how spread are your requests you can hit Lambda limits way before or way after API Gateway throttling limits. I'd say the 2 metrics you are comparing are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

According to the  [API Gateway Request documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html):

> API Gateway limits the steady-state request rate to 10,000 requests per second (rps)

This means that per 100 milliseconds the API can process 1,000 requests.

The comments above are correct in stating that CloudWatch is not giving you the full picture. The actual performance of your system depends on both the runtime of your lambda and the number of concurrent requests.

To better understand what is going on I suggest a using the [Lambda Load Tester](https://github.com/krapes/lambdaLoadTesting) seen in the following images or [building your own](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-aws-lambda-function-concurrency/).

## Testing

The lambda used has the following properties:

1. Upon Invocation, it sleeps for 1 second and then exits.
2. Has a Reserved Concurrency limit of 25, meaning the lambda will only execute 25 concurrent instances. Any surplus will be returned with a 500 error.

### Requests: 1000 Concurrent: 25

In the first test, we'll send 1000 requests in 40 batches of 25 requests each.

Command:

```
bash run.sh -n 1000 -c 25
```

Output:

```
Status code distribution:
  [200] 1000 responses
```

Summary:

In this case, the number of requests was below both the lambda and API Gateways limits. All executions were successful.

### Requests: 1000 Concurrent: 50

In the first test, we'll send 1000 requests in 20 batches of 50 requests each.

Command:

```
bash run.sh -n 1000 -c 50
```

Output:

```
Status code distribution:
  [200] 252 responses
  [500] 748 responses
```

Summary:

In this case, the number of requests was below both the API Gateways limit, so every request was passed to the lambda. However, 50 concurrent requests exceeded the limit of 25 we placed on the lambda, so about 75% of the requests returned a 500 error.

### Requests: 800 Concurrent: 800

In this test, we'll send 800 requests in 1 batch of 800 requests each.

Command:

```
bash run.sh -n 800 -c 800
```

Output:

```
Status code distribution:
  [200] 34 responses
  [500] 765 responses

Error distribution:
  [1]   Get https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dummy: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Summary:

In this case, the number of requests was starting to push the limits of the API Gateway and you can see one of the requests timed out. The 800 concurrent requests well exceeded the 25 reserved concurrency limit we placed on the lambda and in this case, about 95% of the requests returned a 500 error.

### Requests: 3000 Concurrent: 1500

In this test, we'll send 3000 requests in 2 batches of 1500 requests each.

Command:

```
bash run.sh -n 3000 -c 1500
```

Output:

```
Status code distribution:
  [200] 69 responses
  [500] 1938 responses

Error distribution:
  [985] Get https://drlhus6zf3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dummy: dial tcp 52.84.175.209:443: connect: connection refused
  [8]   Get https://drlhus6zf3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/dummy: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Summary:

In this case, the number of requests exceeded the limits of the API Gateway and several of the connection attempts were refused. Those that did pass through the Gateway were still met with the reserved concurrency limit we placed on the lambda and returned a 500 error.

Comment: But if the API Gateway limit is 10,000 requests per second (rps) why you say it exceeded the limits with only 3,000 requests?

Comment: In this example we used the ` Reserved Concurrency` field to reduce the limits for this lamada and produce the results seen above.
(SEE SECTION "TESTING")